# Explicit fundamental solution of a class of hypoelliptic operators

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Good evening,

my question is as follows:

Suppose we are given an operator $$L=a_1x_n\partial_{x_1}+\dotso+a_{n-1}x_n^{n-1}\partial_{x_{n-1}}+\partial_{x_n}^2,$$ for some nonzero constants $a_1,\dotso,a_{n-1}.$ The operator is hypoelliptic, since it satisfies the Hormander condition, that is if we take $X_1=\partial_{x_n}$ and $X_0=a_1x_n\partial_{x_1}+\dotso+a_{n-1}x_n^{n-1}\partial_{x_{n-1}}$, a large enough number of Lie brackets between $X_0$ and $X_1$ generates all $\mathbb R^n$.

So $L$ has a smooth fundamental solution. Does there exists any literature on how to find it explicitly? I know that, more generally,the fundamental solution of $$L=\sum_{i=1}^n(Ax)_i\partial_{x_i}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n(BB^*)_{ij}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}},$$ with $A$ a constant $n\times n$ matrix and $B$ an $n$-dimensional vector, can be interpreted as the probability distribution $\xi_t$ of the stochastic differential equation
$$d\xi_t=A\xi_tdt+Bdw(t),\quad\xi_0=x,$$ with $w(t)$ an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion. Is something along these lines possible even for my operator, or for some general class of operators of that kind?

I feel in the literature something should be known, but I'm really not on my field, so I'm asking you some references to start the research. Many thanks in advance.